# Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine

I am fetching the data using the backbone fetch call. When I tried to test it using the jasmine, I got an error as **Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.**

When I console the valueReturned it provides me the actual value which I need. There is no error in the response. But the only thing which I get on my page is timeout error which I specified above.

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
describe("fetch call", function() {
var valueReturned;
beforeEach(function(done) {
    window.jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
    setTimeout(function () {
    todoCollectionCursor.fetch({
        success : function(collection, response, options) {
            valueReturned = options.xhr.responseText; 
            return valueReturned;
        }
    });
    },500);
});

it("should return string", function(done) {
       console.log(valueReturned);
       expect(typeof valueReturned).toEqual('string');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
describe("fetch call", function() {

jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;

var valueReturned;

beforeEach(function(done) {

    setTimeout(function () {
    todoCollectionCursor.fetch({
        success : function(collection, response, options) {
            valueReturned = options.xhr.responseText; 
            return valueReturned;
        }
    });
    },500);
});

it("should return string", function(done) {
       console.log(valueReturned);
       expect(typeof valueReturned).toEqual('string');
});
});
```

Also, I'm not sure if it's intended, but instead of beforeEach, I would you beforeAll as in this example it will fit better as there is no setup or any initialization

If you code is not working, try this setup, it works for me, and update your code accordingly

```
describe("Testing app: ", function () {

    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 15000;

    beforeAll(function (done) {
        setTimeout(done, 10000);
    });



    it("Verify: true is true with 10 sec delay ", function (done) {
        setTimeout(true.toBe(true), 10000);
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried using **beforeAll** and the code you gave. But it didn't work.

Comment: did you tried to move jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL out of beforeEach?

Comment: Yes, I am checking it.

Comment: Thank you kryp I found the answer for the above question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for it. Since it is an Ajax call I should mock the request. This I found under jasmine-Ajax - https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-ajax

```
it("Response check response when you need it", function() {

              var doneFn = jasmine.createSpy("success");
              $.ajax({
                 url: '/fetch',
                 method: 'GET',
                 success : function(data)
                 {
                     doneFn(data);
                 }
              })
          jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().respondWith({
                "status": 200,
                "contentType": 'text/plain',
                "responseText": '[{title:"Aravinth"}]'
           });
          expect(jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().responseText).toEqual('[{title:"Aravinth"}]');
   });
```